# Группировка связи многие ко многим в форме Django

Tags: python, django, model, many-to-many

подскажите как в шаблоне Django вывести форму такого вида:
 [image: Результат]

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from .util import image_file_name


class SpecializationGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=_('Название'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Группа специализации')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Группы специализаций')

class Specialization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=_('Название'))
    group = models.ForeignKey(SpecializationGroup, verbose_name=_('Группа'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Специализация')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Специализации')

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  verbose_name=_('Пользователь'))
    birthDate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Дата рождения'))
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_file_name, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Изображение профиля'))
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Номер телефона'))
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Веб сайт'))
    town = models.ForeignKey(Towns, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Город'))
    status = models.ForeignKey(Statuses, default=1, verbose_name=_('Статус'))
    summary = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Резюме'))
    skype = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Skype')
    specializations = models.ManyToManyField(Specialization, blank=True, verbose_name='Специализации')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Профиль пользователя')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Профили пользователей')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import *


class SpecializationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    specializations = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Specialization.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('specializations',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, необходимо отсортировать специализации в форме по группам:

```
specializations = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Specialization.objects.all().order_by('group'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Следующим шагом, вы можете в шаблоне пройти циклом по объектам из `queryset`.

Пример шаблона:

```
{% for choice in form.mychoices.field.queryset %}
    {% ifchanged choice.group %}
        <label>{{ choice.group.name }}</label>
    {% endifchanged %}
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="specializations" value="{{ choice.id }}">
        {{ choice.name }}
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

Либо, вы можете сделать на подобии следующего:

```
{% for choice in form.mychoices.field.choices %}
    {{ choice.0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

[Похожая задача](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030534/django-modelchoicefield-how-to-iter-through-the-instances-in-the-template)

Comment: Это то что я искал, спасибо за помощь!! Единственный вопрос как при таком выводе проверить был выбран элемент ранее или нет? Свойство checked которое находится в атрибутах формы ведь не достать если мы проходи циклом по queryset ?

Comment: Есть вариант через `form.my_choice_field.field.choices`, он рассказывается [тут](http://www.ilian.io/django-forms-choicefield-and-custom-html-output/).